# create jquery components using a function and using them in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, components

I want to create some jquery components using a function and use them in the html, but dont know how to do it. Here's what i've attempted.

```
function CreateElement (id, type) {
    $(document).ready (function () {
        if (type == "metricCombobox") {
            var element = $('#' + id).combobox();

            return element;
        }
    });    
}
```

And in the HTML page.

```
<select id="' + CreateElement('metricComboboxSimples', 'metricCombobox') + '" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to create the element in the DOM and then append things to it?
Or can you create all elements in the jQuery? Creating in jQuery, at least for me, is easier to understand, you can control the entire creation of the element and then append it to another element that is already in the DOM or even to the `document.body`... please, take a look at the code below and run the snippet to see if my answer helps you.

```js
var selectOptions= [
      {val : 1, text: 'One'},
      {val : 2, text: 'Two'},
      {val : 3, text: 'Three'}
];

    function CreateElement (id, type, options) {
        $(document).ready (function () {

            if (type == "metricCombobox") {
                var arr = options;
                var element = $('<select>');
                element.attr('id', id); 

                $(arr).each(function() {
                 var selOption = $("<option>");
                 selOption.attr('value', this.val);
                 selOption.text(this.text);
                 element.append(selOption);
                });
                
            }else if (type == 'input'){
                var element = document.createElement('input');
                element.value = 'input created'
                $(element).attr('id',id);
            }

            $("#MyDiv").append(element);
        });    
    }

    CreateElement('metricComboboxSimples', 'metricCombobox', selectOptions);
    CreateElement('testeId', 'input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="MyDiv"></div>
```